# Change a value in a special array, while keeping internal range consistent

Tags: javascript, arrays, range, shift

Let's say I have a specific array:

```
ary = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
```

This is an array used for ranges, where the first range is 0 to 1, the second one is 1 to 2 etc.
The array is build so that any value can never be smaller than the previous one, but they may be equal.

The first and last array items are static, and never changes - thus the sum of the ranges is always 6.

```
function rangeSum(a){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< a.length-1;i++){
        sum += a[i+1]-a[i];
    }
    return sum; //Always equals 6 with this array
}
```

Now I want to change a single range:

```
ary  = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
ary2 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]; //Increases the second range with 1, reduces the third range with 1, the rest are unchanged
```

I would like a function, that takes the reduction in the third range, and spreads it evenly in the rest of the ranges, while maintaining their mutual rangesize.

So instead of ending up with:

```
ary  = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];       //Range [1, 1, 2,   1,    1]
ary2 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];       //Range [1, 2, 1,   1,    1]
```

We get

```
ary2 = [0, 1, 3, 4.5, 5.25, 6];  //Range [1, 2, 1.5, 0.75, 0.75]
```

F.ex:

```
function shiftRange(array, index, increase){
    //Compute new array

    return ary2;
}

ary2 = shiftRange(ary, 2, 1);
```

The function should work with any array size, any index (except first and last) and negative numbers.

Here is the latest code which I tried to get working, but it probably got more complex than necessary - and it doesn't work at all:
http://jsfiddle.net/FN6TX/

Hope somebody can help :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came with:

```
var shiftRange = function (array, pos, amount) {

  //First and last position cannot be modified
  if (pos === 0 || pos === array.length-1) return;

  //Generate new array
  var newArray = array.slice();

  var max = array.length;

  //Calculate the modification ratio of the ranges
  var diference = newArray[max - 1] - newArray[pos];
  var newDiference = diference - amount;
  if (newDiference < 0) {
    newDiference = 0;
  }
  var modificationRatio = newDiference / diference;

  //Calculate the range with the previous item
  var ranges = [0];
  var old = null;
  newArray.forEach(function (item) {
    if (old !== null) {
      ranges.push(item - old);
    }
    old = item;

  });

  //Apply the amount
  newArray[pos] =  newArray[max-1] - newDiference;

  //Apply the ratio
  var aux;
  pos++;
  for (; pos < max - 1; pos++) {
    //get pre-increase range
    aux = ranges[pos];
    //calculate new range
    aux = aux * modificationRatio;
    //aply new range to previous value
    newArray[pos] = newArray[pos - 1] + aux;
  }
  return newArray;
};

//examples
var arr = [1,2,4,6,7,8];
alert(shiftRange(arr, 1, 1));
//1,3,4.666666666666667,6.333333333333334,7.166666666666667,8

arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
alert(shiftRange(arr, 2, 1));
//0,1,3,4.5,5.25,6

arr = [-1, -0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1];
alert(shiftRange(arr, 1, 0.4));
//-1,0.20000000000000007,0.6666666666666667,0.7333333333333334,0.8,1
```

And here is the [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCJJc/1/)

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need - it also supports ranges of 0, which it should. I might need to edit it, so it can do it in reverse, when changing the last values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider just the part of the array that needs to be changed:

```
arr = [2, 4, 5, 6]
```

It goes from 2 to 6.  You want to transform this array so that all the elements have the same proportion to each other but go from 3 to 6.

You can think about this algebraically, with the original data on the horizontal axis of a cartesian graph, and the new data on the vertical axis.  You know for sure 2 should become 3 (so your line has `(2, 3)` in it) and you know for sure 6 should stay 6 (so your line has `(6, 6)`).

The equation of this line is

```
function transform(x) {
    return (6 + 3 * x) / 4;
}
```

You can transform your array, then, with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = transform(arr[i]);
}
```

Of course you can generalize the `6`, `3`, and (two different) `4`s above, and adapt the code so it only runs on a subset of your array.  Multiplication is really good at this kind of transformation, though - whenever you want to "spread something out evenly," you want multiplication.  You don't have to keep track of changes like you're doing in your fiddle.

Update: quiet morning, I suppose: I updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FN6TX/1/